# Using Array.map does not give TypeScript errors for undefined properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

If I have an interface like this:

```
interface OptionsType {
  name: string;
}
```

Then when I try to use that interface with a property that is not defined, I get `Type '{ value: string; disabled: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'OptionsType'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'disabled' does not exist in type 'OptionsType'.`

This is good, I want this error to occur when I make this mistake. My problem comes from when I use this in `Array.map`, it does not give me the error. How can I make it so that my usage of `Array.map` is properly typed?

Errors properly:

```
const optionsArr: OptionsType[] = [
  {
    value: 'hello',
    disabled: false, // error
  },
];

const options: OptionsType = {
  value: 'thing',
  disabled: true, // error
};
```

Does not error:

```
const optionsArrMapped: OptionsType[] = [1, 2].map(num => ({
  value: 'idk',
  disabled: true,
}));

// As an example, using `as` prevents the error from happening. I'm not less concerned about this case.
const optionsAs: OptionsType = {
  value: 'thing',
  disabled: true,
} as OptionsType;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a return type for map function using generics:

```js
const optionsArrMapped: OptionsType[] = [1, 2].map<OptionsType>(num => ({
  value: 'idk',
  disabled: true,
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, that looked like it was going to work. It does make sure that I'm returning all the required properties. But I'm still not seeing any errors when I add random properties to the returned object.

Comment: What version of TypeScript do you use?. Could you show your `tsconfig.json` file? I've checked with version 2.7. VSCode shows me errors when I add random properties or not all required properties.

Comment: Yes, I've checked. It doesn't show error me too. I'll have a look

Comment: TypeScript 3.8.3 is on this project, here's the tsconfig without our paths. 
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
}`

Comment: It seems it still does not error in TypeScript 5.2.2. [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM4AqAnuigN4BQyyAbnADYCuEAXMnmFKAOYDcFAXwoUEuDsmyYc+AIJQobDFjHFSAbQC6yALzI1VZJWrU6TVsgDkACwj162CwBoD1ACbA8cAEb0IrtvD0eBCOyAD0YcjQUNhQBgLOGvwiYmASUmJyUACycOik-mgZ+KoQmjp6AIyhAEwaAHQAtnkAFCCMjToAfMgtRrQMzGwWwK4A1k4G7p4+fmyczKERyCDYUfKxggCUW8mi+Ni+9fbcLZLKsvK5+X5bFEA)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to resolve this is to explicitly type the return value of `Array.map()`:

```js
const optionsArrMapped: OptionsType[] = [1, 2].map((num): OptionsType => ({
  value: 'idk',
  disabled: true,
}));
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM4AqAnuigN4BQyyAbnADYCuEAXMnmFKAOYDcFAXwoUEuDsmyYc%20AIJQobDFjHFSAbQC6yALzI1VZJWrU6TVsgDkACwj162CwBoD1ACbA8cAEb0IrtvD0eBCOyAD0YcjQUNhQBgLOGvwiYmASUmJyUACycOik-mgZ%20KoQmjp6AIyhAEwaAHQAtnkAFC0gjI0AlIrFhCQo2gB8yC1GtAzMbBbArgDWTgbunj5%20bJzMoRFR8rGCXV3JovjYvvX23C2SyrLyufl%20XRRAA)